# using nested try statement in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have some problem with the nested try statements in java and I am asked to use try nested statements instead of if()

here is the some part of the code which I need to use nested try statement

```
 public Date subtractYear() throws Exception
  {
    if (day == 29 && month == 2)
      return new Date(28, month, year - 1);
    else
      return new Date(day, month, year - 1);
  }
```

Comment: Who asked you to use nested try statements instead of if?

Comment: I ll give another part of the code may be it ll be more helpful

Comment: Dude, if and try are two different areas. refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above code is wrong at best and dangerous at worst. There are reasons why the `Date` and `Calendar` classes exist. Managing leap years is one of them.

The above code should only see production in cases where you really understand what you are doing and need to achieve performance by this means. Your best bet is as follows:

```
public Date subtractYear() {
  final Calendar c = new Calendar();
  c.set(year, month, day); // set your class's "current" date
  c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1); // remove 1 year
  return c.getTime(); // get the Date object back from the Calendar
}
```

As an additional comment, using `try-catch` blocks for handling normal program flow is typically a bad way to handle things which you are expecting on a normal basis. The generation of exception stack traces is a costly operation.